# Wordpress header stuck to the top of screen on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I am pretty new to working with wordpress themes and I am having an issue.

Only on mobile devices, not mobile width on desktop, my header will stick to the top of the page but content flows over top of it. I am really not sure what is going on. It doesnt help that the css was originally done by someone else who didn't do a super job. But for the sake of time I needed to code over top of his code. So I am thinking that I am just missing something, although there isn't any place where I added css to the header.

[Here is my site](http://projectlightswitch.org/blogs/#)

Please let me know if there is any further information that I should provide.

php/ html from theme for header:

'

```
<?php // mobile meta (hooray!) ?>
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <?php // icons & favicons (for more: http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/) ?>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/apple-icon-touch.png">
    <link rel="icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.png">
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico">
    <![endif]-->
    <?php // or, set /favicon.ico for IE10 win ?>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#f01d4f">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/win8-tile-icon.png">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#121212">

    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">

    <?php // wordpress head functions ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <?php // end of wordpress head ?>

    <?php // drop Google Analytics Here ?>
    <?php // end analytics ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

    <div id="container">

        <header class="header" role="banner" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">

            <div id="inner-header" class="wrap cf">

                <?php // to use a image just replace the bloginfo('name') with your img src and remove the surrounding <p> ?>
        <a id="logo-link" href="http://projectlightswitch.org"> <img id="logo" class="h1" src="http://projectlightswitch.org/img/logo.png" </img></a>
```

```
                <nav id="main-nav" role="navigation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                             'container' => false,                           // remove nav container
                             'container_class' => 'menu cf',                 // class of container (should you choose to use it)
                             'menu' => __( 'The Main Menu', 'bonestheme' ),  // nav name
                             'menu_class' => 'nav top-nav cf',               // adding custom nav class
                             'theme_location' => 'main-nav',                 // where it's located in the theme
                             'before' => '',                                 // before the menu
                               'after' => '',                                  // after the menu
                               'link_before' => '',                            // before each link
                               'link_after' => '',                             // after each link
                               'depth' => 0,                                   // limit the depth of the nav
                             'fallback_cb' => ''                             // fallback function (if there is one)
                    )); ?>

                </nav>

            </div>

        </header>
```

'

css for the header:
    '
     .header {
      background-color: #00B9A0;}

```
#logo {
float:left
}
 #logo a {
color: white; }


@media (min-width: 799px){
#main-nav{
display:block !important;
}}
@media (max-width: 800px){
#logo {
float:none;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:40%;
}
#main-nav{
display:none;
}

nav ul{
margin:0 !important;
float:none;
}
nav ul li{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
margin:0 !important;

}
nav ul li a{
display: inline-block;
width:100%;
border-top: 3px solid #fff; }

#mobile-menu-toggle{
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:20px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#mobile-menu-toggle span, #mobile-menu-toggle span:before, #mobile-menu-toggle span:after                     

{

  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
width: 35px;
background: white;
position: absolute;
display: block;
content: '';
}
#mobile-menu-toggle span:before {
top: -10px;

}
#mobile-menu-toggle span:after {
 bottom: -10px; 

}

#mobile-menu-toggle span, #mobile-menu-toggle span:before, #mobile-menu-toggle span:after                            

{ 
transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#mobile-menu-toggle.active span {
background-color: transparent;
}
#mobile-menu-toggle.active span:before, #mobile-menu-toggle.active span:after {
top: 0;
}
#mobile-menu-toggle.active span:before {
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#mobile-menu-toggle.active span:after {
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.hidden{
display:none;}
}
'
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCiQe.png) what happens.

Comment: Could you please paste some of your header code, and preferably CSS code that relates to it instead of an external link to your site?

Comment: @Lee done. please let me know if you need anything else. I appreciate you taking a look

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but it seems to work fine. Tested on a Iphone 5.

Comment: Really? The header isnt sticking as you scroll down? Mine is both when i emulate iphone 5 on chrome and when I used my phone.

Comment: Nope, it floats away when scrolling down. Could you attach a screenshot showing this to your question?

Comment: @Topr I added an image. Would you mind telling me if the mobile menu icon is pushed down on your mobile? It is on my device but not on the chrome device emulator.

Comment: It's working as intended for me, see this link: http://i.imgur.com/Oc6NOU9.png However, I noticed that your menu icon is white, but when i visit the site, its black. Maybe you have a caching issue?

Comment: Are you going to the site via the link i posted? Because there is a old version of the site up that I am going to replace once I solve these issues.

Comment: Yeah my bad, when switching to mobile I forgot to add /blogs/. The error occurs now.

Comment: ah okay. Well, if you have time and are able to figure anything out I would really appreciate it.